# .htaccess - redirecting ONLY root (Codeigniter / WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I currently have a site created in codeigniter in a folder `/ci/`

I currently installed WordPress in the root directory.

What I want is the site to perform as normal with CI but for the main root url (www.example.com) I want it to load the the Wordpress site (hence why i installed it in the root)

I am trying in the `.htaccess` to `IGNORE` the main site from being redirected to CI with:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/`

But as expected this means all the the other CI links (e.g. http://www.example.com/test which is http://www.example.com/ci/test) no longer work.

---

This is my current .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ci/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-includes/?$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that www.example.com is wordpress site. and in wordpress site a folder named CI holds a CI website.

Ok. So follow these steps:
First allow /CI directory from your wordpress site. include this line

```
RewriteRule ^CI/(.*)$ /CI/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and in CI site you have htaccess just add this line there.

```
RewriteBase /CI
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: I tried this but only
http://www.example.com/ci/
works

http://www.example.com/ci/test/
OR
http://www.example.com/test/ (which is what i want to work, don't want ci in the url)

have a 404 Not Found error

Comment: what you mean by test/ here? Please mention your directory structure here for better understanding.

Comment: test is a controller in CI. I still want all the controllers in CI to work.

my directory is wordpress in the root, and a CI folder in the root which has all the CI files.

Comment: I also want my controllers in CI to work without the CI in front.

e.g. for test controller in CI, 

www.example.com/ci/test

i would want it to also work as

www.example.com/test

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to say what you want cannot be done, but for the sake of 'keeping your house in order', you should move the /test folder to ci/test and be done with it. Otherwise you are confusing both WordPress working out of your root directory and Code Igniter working out of your /ci folder.